# Where JVM keeps information about reference and object types

Tags: java, jvm, java-memory-model

I am trying to deepen my knowledge in  Java Memory Model and JVM.

The basic concept is easy, but I cannot understand where JVM keeps information about types for primitives, objects and references.

For example

1. we have variable `int i = 0`.
   This value is stored in thread's stack. This is just a 4 bytes that contains value `0x0000` in RAM or/and CPU cache. But it doesn't contain any information about its type.
   Imagine that you can get access to these bytes in memory directly. You cannot be sure that it is a integer. As far as i understand you won't be able to say nothing about its type. This is just 4 bytes information.

Thus, JVM has to keep some information about its type in other place, but where and how JVM keeps it?

2. Reference object

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}

A obj = new B();
```

In this case we have something like this:

```
| stack |        |HEAP|         |PermGen|

 "reference" ----> "Object"          "A", "B".
```

Reference is located in stack and has type "A", but reference contains only information where "Object" is stored. It has 8bytes (can be compressed to 4byte if JVM uses less then 32GB). It doesn't have any information about its type in these 8 bytes.

"Object" is located in heap and has type "B". I don't know if it has there any information about its type...

3. References with generics.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Where and how JVM keeps information about each type for objects and references?

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials, descriptions and explanations of the questions you are asking online. Where have you looked already? Also your question seems pretty broad.

Comment: 2. when it has the address, it can follow that pointer and from there follow the class pointer and check. https://dzone.com/articles/java-object-memory - 1 and 3 will also be stored mostly in the class, although some checks may be implicit because the compiler prevents access of wrong types.

Comment: By the way: "The Java Memory Model (JMM) describes which executions of a program are legal by determining what value(s) can be observed when reading a shared variable according to certain rules." it's not about the memory layout of objects or primitives.

Comment: It's useful thank.

Comment: Could you please tell something about references and primitives? They also have types

Comment: @ Underbalanced, I have tried to get this information from JVM and JMM specifications. Also Google provides a lot of information where jvm stores values, but I haven't found information where it stores information about types for references and primitives.

Comment: Types for references and primitives is encoded in two places: a) in the types of fields, method/constructor parameters, and method return types (this info is part of the Java classfile, a byte array kept in the "permgen" or another equivalent internal JVM memory area); and b) in the bytecode instructions that load/store/cast values from/into local variables or the stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I cannot understand where JVM keeps information about types for primitives, objects and references.

The JVM has a space (Perm Gen or Metaspace) where records all type information and code.

> This is just 4 bytes information.

Yes, it could be an boolean, an int or a 32-bit reference.Most likely it is in a register which means it doesn't even use any memory.

> JVM has to keep some information about its type in other place, but where and how JVM keeps it?

Actually it doesn't.  If it way to look up such information on every access it would be extremely slow.  Instead it has machine code which puts a 4 byte value into a register and then just assumes it is the type it expect it to be.

The only thing it needs to keep track of is which registers hold references and which hold primitives.  It needs this to perform a GC.

The code which is being run can have meta information about which registers and which stack locations have references. Registers are not allocated dynamically except when the code is recompiled.

> References with generics. List list = new ArrayList<>(); Where and how JVM keeps information about each type for objects and references?

It doesn't.  Generics are a compile time feature.

There is some information you can obtain at runtime, however this is not available on objects, only on classes.

Comment: "Generics are a compile time feature." Actually, in Java generics are much more than just a compile time feature.

Comment: @Rogério you can get information from classes via reflection, however they don't do anything at runtime.

Comment: They "don't do anything" in C# as well (which has no erasure). The point is to avoid phrases like "generics are a *compile time* feature", because many novices do end up believing that all generic type information gets "erased" by the compiler and is not available at runtime, when in fact the Java Reflection API was greatly extended in Java 5 with new methods, etc. that support runtime recovery and use of generic type information.

Comment: **Thanks Peter for answer and  everyone who provided comments**

Comment: @Rogério yes, reflection can be used on class information, but you can't get generic information for instances, only the classes they are instance of as in the example given.

Comment: Yes, of course. I am just pointing out that Java generics is *also* a "runtime feature", not just a compile time feature. Many Java libraries (such as Mockito, or my own library JMockit) do take advantage of runtime generic type information.

Comment: @Rogério while you can do many things at runtime, I would say that access to generics information is a feature of a library rather than Java itself.

Comment: Well, runtime access to generics is provided by the Java Reflection API, a standard library. But there is more to it than that, since generic type information is encoded in generic type and method signatures in the Java classfile (the binary format for ".class" files which contains bytecode, constants, and type declarations). Other libraries (eg., ASM) also provide access to this information. The classfile format, together with the Reflection API, was also extended in Java 5 for the generics support; all of this is part of the *runtime* - not the compile time - feature of Java generics.